# How to import CSV to seperate variables in order to 'count' for Matplotlib Bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, matplotlib

I am currently programming some descriptive analytics on a CSV file.

What I want to do;
**Create a bar chart of Location occurrence within the CSV file and plot to bar chart.**

I am wondering if there is a way of importing the 'many' different locations as separate variables as I need to add 1 to each variable when the regex is matched against the CSV.

The CSV column is called; (Some are abbreviated for ease as variables)

Borough:

```
COL = 0
Barnet = 0
Bexley = 0
BAD = 0
Brent = 0
Bromley = 0
Camden = 0
Croydon = 0
Ealing = 0
Enfield = 0
Greenwich = 0
Hackney = 0
HAF = 0
Haringey = 0
Harrow = 0
Havering = 0
Hillingdon = 0
Hounslow = 0
Islington = 0
KAC = 0
KUT = 0
Lambeth = 0
Lewisham = 0
Merton = 0
Newham = 0
Redbridge = 0
RUT = 0
Southwark = 0
Sutton = 0
TowerHamlets = 0
WalthamForest = 0
Wandsworth = 0
Westminster = 0
OuterBorough = 0
InnerBorough = 0*
```

Here is my current code with the output of the image below:

```
#Start of Imports 
import csv 
import sys 
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import re 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
#End of Imports

#Start of Declarations 
COL = 0
Barnet = 0
Bexley = 0
BAD = 0
Brent = 0
Bromley = 0
Camden = 0
Croydon = 0
Ealing = 0
#This is as far as I got when I thought something was wrong?
Enfield = 0
Greenwich = 0
Hackney = 0
HAF = 0
Haringey = 0
Harrow = 0
Havering = 0
Hillingdon = 0
Hounslow = 0
Islington = 0
KAC = 0
KUT = 0
Lambeth = 0
Lewisham = 0
Merton = 0
Newham = 0
Redbridge = 0
RUT = 0
Southwark = 0
Sutton = 0
TowerHamlets = 0
WalthamForest = 0
Wandsworth = 0
Westminster = 0
OuterBorough = 0
InnerBorough = 0
#End of Declarations

#Starts reading 'csv file'  
csv = pd.read_csv ('land-area-population-density-london.csv') #Not sure what this does, index_col=3)

#Start of IF Statement  
csva = np.array(csv) 
for column in np.arange(0, csva.shape[0]): 
    if re.match(r"Barnet", str(csva[column][2])) is not None:         
        Barnet = Barnet + 1
    elif re.match(r"Bexley", str(csva[column][2])) is not None:         
        Bexley = Bexley + 1
    elif re.match(r"City of London", str(csva[column][2])) is not None:         
        COL = COL + 1
    elif re.match(r"Barking and Dagenham", str(csva[column][2])) is not None:         
        BAD = BAD + 1
    elif re.match(r"Brent", str(csva[column][2])) is not None:         
        Brent = Brent + 1
    elif re.match(r"Bromley", str(csva[column][2])) is not None:         
        Bromley = Bromley + 1
    elif re.match(r"Camden", str(csva[column][2])) is not None:         
        Camden = Camden + 1
    elif re.match(r"Croydon", str(csva[column][2])) is not None:         
        Croydon = Croydon + 1
    elif re.match(r"Ealing", str(csva[column][2])) is not None:         
        Ealing = Ealing + 1
#End of IF Statement

#Start of graph fields
#Below: Places is the labels for the placesvar
places = ('Barnet', 'Bexley', 'City of London', 'Barking and Dagenham', 'Brent', 'Bromley', 'Camden', 'Croydon', 'Ealing')
#Below: placesvar the actual 'places' pulled from CSV
placesvar = [Barnet, Bexley, COL, BAD, Brent, Bromley, Camden, Croydon, Ealing]
#Y Positioning numpy.arange (Again no idea what this does) length 'places pulled from csv'
y_pos = np.arange(len(placesvar)) 
#End of graph fields

#Start of Graph positions and Names 
plt.bar(y_pos, placesvar, align='center') 
plt.xticks(y_pos, places, rotation=60) 
plt.ylabel('No. of occurance') 
plt.xlabel('Locations') 
plt.title('Occurance of Locations') 
#plt.savefig('file.png')(Commented out for testing) 
#End of Graph positions and Names
plt.show()
```

This is the output of my current code. This is missing a few variables from the column 'Borough'.
Image:
[image: This is the output of my current code. This is missing a few variables from the column 'Borough'.]

I apologize for any glaring issues, I'm relatively new to Python.

---

Here is the output to adding: `print(csv.head())`

```
       Codes             ...             Population per hectare 2011
0  E09000001             ...                               23.405268
1  E05000026             ...                               99.968726
2  E05000027             ...                               76.304188
3  E05000028             ...                               89.914330
4  E05000029             ...                               29.647929

[5 rows x 10 columns]
```

[**FIG1**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IHDF.png)

Comment: Can you add `print(csv.head())` after the `read_csv` line and show us the output?

Comment: Apologies but I can't seem to add code to the commend, I haven't got used to the format of the site yet.

Comment: `           Codes             ...             Population per hectare 2011
0  E09000001             ...                               23.405268
1  E05000026             ...                               99.968726
2  E05000027             ...                               76.304188
3  E05000028             ...                               89.914330
4  E05000029             ...                               29.647929

[5 rows x 10 columns]`

Comment: This is unreadable as a comment. Try placing the result as a nice looking table in your question and clearly asking what you want. It sounds like your problem can be solved with one line of code but it is still somewhat unclear what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Apologies again, Ctrl + k doesn't work in my browser or any other ones I tried. I have appended the code output to the bottom of my original question.

Comment: I would like to learn how to pull (import?) CSV data from a specific column and turn that data into variables. These variables must have an value of [0] to begin with until regex has matched a specific string to that data in the same column then add 1 to the variable value from which  I can turn those variables into a bar chart using Matplotlib.

Comment: I believe you should not turn your csv into variables, but read-in the csv into pandas and then just count occurrences or something like this, creating ONE variable containing boroughs and corresponding counts. Basically, what you are looking for is a pivot table?

Comment: This seems like too much work. Could you run `df = pd.read_csv(...)` and then `df.iloc[:,2].value_counts().plot(kind='hist')`? Your goal seems to be counting occurrences of locations in the third column of your csv file. Since we can't see the third column here, it is hard to give an exact answer.

Comment: Running the code you provided gave me a chart with Frequency 0-14 Y-axis and 0-25 X-axis. I would like to have the names (locations) and their occurrences within the column, I will append the image to the Original post named 'FIG1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got your question right...

This is a simplified example of your problem (I believe):

Input data test.csv:

```
    Codes   Borough
0   E1  A
1   E2  B
2   E1  A
3   E1  A
4   E3  C
5   E2  B
6   E1  A
7   E3  C
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read-in data
data = pd.read_csv('./test.csv', sep='\t') #adjust sep to your needs

# count occurences
occurrences = data.loc[:, 'Borough'].value_counts()

# plot histogram
plt.bar(occurrences.keys(), occurrences)
```

[image: simple example histogram]

Instead of `data.loc` you could also use `data.iloc[:, 2]` to select the 3rd column instead of the column named `Borough`.

Comment: This is what I needed, didn't realize how over-complicated I was making it. Thanks for the help!